# Count number of times the sub string occurs in string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am a Python newbies. I am struck with this quiz. It should use a `while` or `for` loop.
Here is a quiz question:

Assume s is a string of lower case characters.

Write a program that prints the number of times the string 'bob' occurs in s. For example, if s = 'azcbobobegghakl', then your program should print

Number of times bob occurs is: 2

This is my code.

```
count = 0
string = 'bob'
strings = s.find(string)

for i in s:
    if strings != -1:
    count = count + 1
print(count)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What's the problem? There's no question here.

Comment: You may want to have a look at Boyer-Moore algorithm.

Comment: `sum([1 for i in range(len(s)-len(key)) if (s[i:i+len(key)] == key)])`